# Does Eevee support Animated Textures?

Tags: animation, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I am not able to use an animated texture (image in sequence) for objects in Eevee (Blender 2.80)

Has someone managed to use this successfully?

If so, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about issues with experimental development versions of Blender

Answer (score 2):

Animated textures are supported for Eevee as of the latest builds. The change was added during the week 11-15 February.

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.8 is in development. It's an unfinished & unstable alpha product constantly changing hour after hour. So if you're not prepared to constantly have issues like that, consider waiting for the 2.80 release.

---

For now, it seems to be displayed correctly, but the frames do not update through time. Check your UVs.

Comment: Thank you ..... well, if I wait, I'll wait. but I've seen this project and thought I could develop it too

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9xGIu9u-f4